# Save Dates / Events with JQuery Mobile ui-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-mobile

I am looking into the JQuery Mobile Calendar UI-DatePicker.

It can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Does anyone know how to save dates / events on it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by saving dates/events? Can you give us an example?

Comment: If you look here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/  ... what I'm basically asking is if there's a way to save selected dates and add/save events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery Mobile UI-Datepicker, just like any other datepicker widget, simply updates the value placed in the input box. If a user clicks the calendar day for today, the text '04/05/2011' will be placed in the input box. The widget does not do anything more than that.

It is your job to take the value in that input box and do what you want with it. Typically, you will wait for a user to submit a form, grab the date they entered, validate it, and store it somewhere.

As for where to store it, that is up to you. One good way to store things in a Javascript web app like this is using a cross browser storage library like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the date picker confused with a calendar control. This control is for selecting dates.

Comment: All I know about it is in this link: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/  .. I haven't been able to find out anymore about it as it's still under test.